# couldn't send mail from mandrill in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mandrill

Hello I am newbie to ruby on rails, I am trying to send mail from mandrill and following this documentation https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/guides/send-first-email/
but somehow I am getting this error

```
Error: {:status=>500, :response_body=>"{\"status\":\"error\",\"code\":-1,\"name\":\"ValidationError\",\"message\":\"You must specify a message value\"}"}
```

here is my code

```
client = MailchimpTransactional::Client.new('xxxxxxxxxRWX-nA')
message = {
  from_email: "hello@xxxxx.co",
  subject: "Hello world",
  text: "Welcome to Mailchimp Transactional!",
  to: [
    {
      email: "xxxxxx@gmail.com",
      type: "to"
    }
  ]
}

begin
  response = client.messages.send(message)
  p response
rescue MailchimpTransactional::ApiError => e
  puts "Error: #{e}"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have to pass it to the client with a key value of message as follows:

This is incorrect:

```rb
response = client.messages.send(message)
```

This is correct:

```rb
response = client.messages.send(message: message)
```

The transactional email documentation on [Mailchimp's website](https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/guides/send-first-email/#send-your-first-email) is incorrect.